# What is the most efficient way to count all the occurrences of a specific character in a PHP string?

Tags: php, string

What is the most efficient way to count all the occurrences of a specific character in a PHP string?

Comment: Do you mean in a string? And do you want the number found returned?

Comment: the question is certainly efficient in its use of characters

Comment: Yeah, is Stack overflow the new Twitter?

Comment: Hey, you are using way too many words. "PHP: find character occurences? | most efficient way?" should be shorter.

Comment: To get an array of all the character counts, check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

Answer (score 37):

use this:

```
echo substr_count("abca", "a"); // will echo 2
```

Comment: for multibyte strings use mb_substr_count()

Comment: Also, note that the needle is `case-sensitive`!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not feed the character to [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)?

Comment: It's not efficient to use a regex just to look for one static character.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of a response you're looking for, but here's a function that might do it:

```
function findChar($c, $str) {
    indexes = array();
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str{$i}==$c) $indexes[] = $i;
    }
    return $indexes;
}
```

Pass it the character you're looking for and the string you want to look:

```
$mystring = "She shells out C# code on the sea shore";
$mychar = "s";
$myindexes = $findChar($mychar, $mystring);
print_r($myindexes);
```

It should give you something like

```
Array (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 31
    [4] => 35
)
```

or something...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be repeatedly checking the same string, it'd be smart to have some sort of trie or even assoc array for it otherwise, the straightforward way to do it is...

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
  if($s[i] == $c)
    echo "{$s[i]} at position $i";
```

Comment: what about if we want case insensitive search? <?php
`$str='fksjfkds fddshfhhfahhdF asdfhas  aunfa fdsjf ds';
$c='f';
$indexes=0;
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
  if ($str[$i]==$c){
   $indexes++;
  }
}
echo $indexes;` but it does not count capital "F"