# Php check exist have how many random int numbers in string

Tags: php, random, integer

I have rand function like;

```
$mynumbers = rand(1111,9999);
echo $mynumbers;
```

Example output is
3582

and I have another strings

```
$mystring = "Ja9Js78I4PhXiF464R6s7ov8IUF";  (Have 1 number, must be turn 1 (only 8 have))
$mystring2 = "Ja3Js73I4P1X5iF564R8s2ov8IUF"; (Have 4 numbers, must be turn 4 (have all of them))
```

And i want to know this with function ;

**$mystring is have, how many numbers ?  inside $mynumbers** and how many time ? passed when this process ?  How can i do it ?

Comment: No string functions in swift development? How would you pseudo code it?

Comment: i need this with php :) for backend

Comment: Giving you a hard time. I'll post something in a sec if nobody else does.

Comment: Looks the same in C, fortran, just about any language you can name... here's some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933253/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-count-all-the-occurrences-of-a-specific-charac

Comment: @ficuscr yeah with substr_count says me count but i have 4 character and not inline, if i use it i need to work this function x4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per your last comment. Treat the integer as a string (PHP is good at that). And iterate by character.

```
<?php

$foo = '1234';

$mystring = [];
$mystring[] = 'A1B2KLDLDF3'; //3
$mystring[] = 'XXXX4XXXX'; //1

foreach ($mystring as $key => $string) {
    echo "mystring {$key}: ";
    $c = 0;

    foreach(str_split($foo) as $char) {
        $c = $c + substr_count($string, $char);
    }
    echo $c . '<br/>';
}
```

> mystring 0: 3
>
> mystring 1: 1

As this is PHP you also need to be aware of `mb_` multibyte functions. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php

**Update:**

Sounds like you should clean up the string you are checking then if you want to discard all duplicates... Could then of course use a `substr` or other method perhaps more performant than `substr_count`.

```
$mystring = 'A111111B2KLDLDF333'; //3
$mystring = implode('',array_unique(str_split($mystring)));
//gives 'A1B2KLDF3'
```

Comment: checking 1 sec. dude

Comment: when i use this with like this gives output = 1110

Comment: must be , output with $bar = 3

Comment: yeah know worked but, when i add mystring inside many 33333 , adding +3

Comment: example change $mystring[] = 'A1B2KLDLDF3';  to  $mystring[] = 'A1B2KLDLDF333'; will be output 5 , must be 3

Comment: Fix the grammar on last part of your question and I'll add that to my answer :)

Comment: okay , change $mystring[] = 'A1B2KLDLDF3'; to $mystring[] = 'A1B2KLDLDF333'; after run this , will be output  mystring 0: 5, but must be mystring 0: 3

Comment: i checked updated 2 codes but shows mystring 0: 1, must be mystring 0: 3 , i added A1B2KLDLDF3 last char after 33 so this is must be not important so 3 have

Comment: same shows dublicate counts if i add mystring inside 33 or 11 adding output + 2

Comment: @ficyscr gives Warning: str_split() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: thank you man. only 1 thing how can i take milisecond time ? when this func start and stop between so have many mystrings i need to know time